# Saving title of NSSegmentedControl in User defaults

Tags: cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

Thanks for the help:

I manually set the title of a segController segment from a textField input like this:

```
NSString  *labelString = [textField stringValue];
(textField.stringValue = labelString);
[segControl setLabel: labelString forSegment:8];
```

I loose the new label when quitting. How can I save the edited segController label string in NSUserDefaults as I would with a text string, like this:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [textField objectValue] forKey: @"newDefault"];
```

My action needs to occasionally set a new title. Point is the label string is not permanently fixed.

thanks.

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the segment number, You can do the following:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if(defaults) {
    [defaults setValue: [segControl labelForSegment:8] forKey: @"segmentLabel"];
}
else {
    // handle error
}
```

Alternatively you can just save the string to `NSUserDefaults` whenever you set the label like in your above example.